# Hazelcast Spring Boot java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, spring-boot, hazelcast

I am starting hazelcast instance in my spring boot application.

Hazelcast configuration

```
@Configuration
@EnableCaching
public class HazelcastConfig {
    @Bean
    public Config hazelCastConfig() {
        final Config config = new Config();
        config.setClassLoader(getClass().getClassLoader());
        config.setInstanceName("cache");
        return config;
    }

    @Bean
    public HazelcastInstance hazelcastInstance() {
        return Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(hazelCastConfig());
    }
}
```

And it fails time to time with class not found exception when I call my HTTP endpoint that queries data from hazelcast Map.

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.someOrg.SomeClass
at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedWebappClassLoader.loadClass(TomcatEmbeddedWebappClassLoader.java:70) ~[spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1137) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar!/:8.5.34]
at com.hazelcast.nio.ClassLoaderUtil.tryLoadClass(ClassLoaderUtil.java:173) ~[hazelcast-3.9.4.jar!/:3.9.4]
at com.hazelcast.nio.ClassLoaderUtil.loadClass(ClassLoaderUtil.java:147) ~[hazelcast-3.9.4.jar!/:3.9.4]
at com.hazelcast.nio.IOUtil$ClassLoaderAwareObjectInputStream.resolveClass(IOUtil.java:593) ~[hazelcast-3.9.4.jar!/:3.9.4]
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1826) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1713) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2000) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1535) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:422) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.JavaDefaultSerializers$JavaSerializer.read(JavaDefaultSerializers.java:79) ~[hazelcast-3.9.4.jar!/:3.9.4]
at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.JavaDefaultSerializers$JavaSerializer.read(JavaDefaultSerializers.java:72) ~[hazelcast-3.9.4.jar!/:3.9.4]
at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.StreamSerializerAdapter.read(StreamSerializerAdapter.java:48) ~[hazelcast-3.9.4.jar!/:3.9.4]
at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.AbstractSerializationService.toObject(AbstractSerializationService.java:191) ~[hazelcast-3.9.4.jar!/:3.9.4]
at com.hazelcast.query.impl.CachedQueryEntry.getValue(CachedQueryEntry.java:75) ~[hazelcast-3.9.4.jar!/:3.9.4]
at com.hazelcast.query.impl.CachedQueryEntry.getTargetObject(CachedQueryEntry.java:108) ~[hazelcast-3.9.4.jar!/:3.9.4]
at com.hazelcast.query.impl.QueryableEntry.extractAttributeValue(QueryableEntry.java:81) ~[hazelcast-3.9.4.jar!/:3.9.4]
at com.hazelcast.query.impl.QueryableEntry.getAttributeValue(QueryableEntry.java:48) ~[hazelcast-3.9.4.jar!/:3.9.4]
at com.hazelcast.query.impl.predicates.AbstractPredicate.readAttributeValue(AbstractPredicate.java:132) ~[hazelcast-3.9.4.jar!/:3.9.4]
at com.hazelcast.query.impl.predicates.AbstractPredicate.apply(AbstractPredicate.java:57) ~[hazelcast-3.9.4.jar!/:3.9.4]
at com.hazelcast.query.PredicateBuilder.apply(PredicateBuilder.java:51) ~[hazelcast-3.9.4.jar!/:3.9.4]
at com.hazelcast.map.impl.query.PartitionScanRunner.run(PartitionScanRunner.java:97) ~[hazelcast-3.9.4.jar!/:3.9.4]
at com.hazelcast.map.impl.query.CallerRunsPartitionScanExecutor.execute(CallerRunsPartitionScanExecutor.java:42) ~[hazelcast-3.9.4.jar!/:3.9.4]
at com.hazelcast.map.impl.query.QueryRunner.runPartitionScanQueryOnGivenOwnedPartition(QueryRunner.java:172) ~[hazelcast-3.9.4.jar!/:3.9.4]
at com.hazelcast.map.impl.query.QueryPartitionOperation.run(QueryPartitionOperation.java:55) ~[hazelcast-3.9.4.jar!/:3.9.4]
at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.OperationRunnerImpl.run(OperationRunnerImpl.java:194) ~[hazelcast-3.9.4.jar!/:3.9.4]
at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.OperationRunnerImpl.run(OperationRunnerImpl.java:409) ~[hazelcast-3.9.4.jar!/:3.9.4]
at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationexecutor.impl.OperationThread.process(OperationThread.java:115) ~[hazelcast-3.9.4.jar!/:3.9.4]
at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationexecutor.impl.OperationThread.run(OperationThread.java:100) ~[hazelcast-3.9.4.jar!/:3.9.4]
```

Tried with `config.setClassLoader(getClass().getClassLoader());` in hazelcast configuration class and without it - it fails after some time with the same ClassNotFoundException issue.

Why hazelcast fails with this issue and how to fix it ?

Comment: How do you use `com.someOrg.SomeClass`? Is it an entry, EntryProcessor, Listener, etc. class?

Comment: It is simple POJO: `Collection<SomeClass> o = map.values(getPredicate());`

Comment: when you say it fails time to time, do you imply every time you query or occasionally? What else changes on server side? That error simply means that the class definition does not exist on Hazelcast's class path. So the most important thing for you to figure out is the reason why com.someOrg.SomeClass is not on class path.

Comment: I have a docker image and when I deploy it and call HTTP API - I can reproduce 2 options here: 1. it can work all the time until redeploy; 2. it can fail all the time until redeploy. It is simple Spring Boot app without any additional logic with class loading, etc. (hazelcast cluster with 1 member only)

Comment: But need to mention, the issue is rarely reproduced. Almost always it works well.

Comment: As @wildnez mentioned, can you please confirm that the `SomeClass` definition is on the classpath?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I fixed the issue by using Hazelcast feature [User Code Deployment](https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/latest/manual/html-single/#configuring-user-code-deployment)

Configuration file that works for me

```
@Configuration
@EnableCaching
public class HazelcastConfig {
    @Bean
    public Config hazelCastConfig() {
        final Config config = new Config();            
        config.setClassLoader(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader());

        final UserCodeDeploymentConfig distCLConfig = config.getUserCodeDeploymentConfig();
        distCLConfig.setEnabled(true)
          .setClassCacheMode(UserCodeDeploymentConfig.ClassCacheMode.ETERNAL)
          .setProviderMode(UserCodeDeploymentConfig.ProviderMode.LOCAL_CLASSES_ONLY);

        return config;
    }

    @Bean
    public HazelcastInstance hazelcastInstance() {
        return Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(hazelCastConfig());
    }
}
```